# Resource ID #0x0 React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to set an icon in Android with react-native. My code looks like this:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
  actions={[]}
  navIcon={require('image!test')}
  onIconClicked={navigationOperations.pop}
  style={styles.toolbar}
  titleColor="white"
  title={route.event.title} />
```

I've got a non-corrupt `test.png` file under `app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/test.png` (after adding the image I've run `react-native run-android`) and I'm getting a Resource ID #0x0 :

[image: Resource ID #0x0]

However, if I change the image name to something bogus, the error

> "Requiring unknown module "image!testttt". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager"

I don't know what's going on, I've seen an exact example of this in react-native Movies example, that actually works in my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was happening. When I created my project react-native created mipmap directories: `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi`, etc.

These directories in Android are for icons only. I deleted these directories and created drawable ones and put my icon application inside `drawable`. I adjusted my `AndroidManifest` to point to `@drawable/icon`. After this a rebuild the android application and relaunch the packager. It started working right after that with react-native 0.11.0